# Not able to launch Genymotion emulator

Tags: android, genymotion

### Not able to launch Genymotion emulator for the first time after configuring the settings

- I have downloaded and installed the Gennymotion Software
- I followed proper steps ...

**I dont know whether the settings i am making error to configure it properly ....**

---

*After installing G.Motion i get like below*

[image]

### After i click ok

[image]

**Then a error screen pops like this !**

[image]

### How to resolve this error ?

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but the same happened to me when I tried to launch a device that needed more memory than what I had available. I changed to one that needed less memory and it works great!

Comment: How to change to one that need less memory .... I mean where i can find the setting ..... ?

Comment: Just before adding a new device, the first screen shows info about the device. There you can see how much memory that device needs.

Comment: your virtualbox already installed and IDE closed?